# Text binding elements of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, binding

I have two arrays chosenItems and datas, I want to get data from datas and the column information form the chosenItems array. How ever it is giving me blank spaces instead of the data in datas array.

```
ko.applyBindings({
            chosenItems: [
              {
                  headerText: "C1",
                  alignment:"left"
              },
              {
                  headerText: "C3",
                  alignment:"right"
              }
            ],
            datas: [
              {
                  C1:"Peter",
                  Age: 21
              },
              {
                  C2: "Pater",
                  Age: 31
              },
              {
                  C3: "Cecel",
                  Age: 23
              }
            ]
        });

 <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data:chosenItems,as :'column'}">
         <tr data-bind=" foreach: {data:datas,as: 'datum'}">
              <td>
                   <span data-bind="text: datum[column.headerText]"></span>
              </td>
         </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Here the use case is that datas is dynamic and there could be any data,but I only choose to display certain items which is controlled by the choosenItems array .

Comment: how does your `datas` array looks like?

Comment: @Thunder  just add `$parent` to inner foreach (on tr) `datas` check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26978/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your array and data is getting populated from ViewModel.

Have you tried the below,

```
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
```

Can you show your viewmodel code, specifically for those two array's `chosenItems` and `datas`.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your scenario, you should use "table" element:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
            chosenItems: [
              {
                  headerText: "C1",
                  alignment:"left"
              },
              {
                  headerText: "C3",
                  alignment:"right"
              }
            ],
            datas: [
              {
                  C1:"Peter",
                  Age: 21
              },
              {
                  C2: "Pater",
                  Age: 31
              },
              {
                  C3: "Cecel",
                  Age: 23
              }
            ]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: chosenItems, as: 'column' }">
         <tr data-bind="foreach: { data:$parent.datas, as: 'datum' }">
              <td>
                   <span data-bind="text: datum[column.headerText]"></span>
              </td>
         </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Updated

I've updated view model according updated question text.
You can also use "$root.datas" as well as "$parent.datas".